# PrimeFaces contextMenus items enabled on selected row value basis

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I have a `dataTable` which lists jobs. These jobs can be enabled/disabled. Currently I am using a `contextMenu` to enable/disable the selected job. This does work fine though.

Now I want to enable/disable the menuItems in the `contextMenu` based on the job status (job enabled/disabled).

If a job is enabled, the "Enable" option should be disabled. If the job is disabled, the "Disable" option should be disabled.

Following is the code I have so far:

```
<p:tab title="Jobs" id="jobTab">
    <p:dataTable id="jobs" var="job" value="#{model.jobs}"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{model.selection}"
        onRowClick="" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="600"
        rowKey="#{job.jobName}">
        <p:column headerText="Group Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{job.jobGroup}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Job Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{job.jobName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Job Enabled">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{job.enabled}" disabled="true" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:contextMenu for="jobs" id="ctxJobs" widgetVar="ctxJobs">
        <p:menuitem value="Enable" update="jobs" action="enableJob"
            disabled="#{model.selection.enabled}" />
        <p:menuitem value="Disable" update="jobs" action="disableJob"
            disabled="#{!model.selection.enabled}" />
        <p:separator />
        <p:menuitem value="Start" action="startJob" />
    </p:contextMenu>
```

The `contextMenu`s actions refer to view-state transitions of `spring webflow`, though that shouldn't be the issue as webflow is not rendering the parts.

Right now, the context menu does enable/disable the items when an action was performed. What I mean with that is following: A job is enabled. I right-click the row for the context menu. At first, "Enable" is enabled and "Disable" is disabled. So now I can press "Enable". This causes the backing data to reload and in turn, the context menu reloads as well. If I right-click on the same row (its still enabled), the context menu now has "Enable" disabled and "Disable" enabled. Actually it doesn't matter which row I select, the items don't update unless I perform any action.

This is not very user friendly. Also I think that refreshing the data every time I select a new row or open the context menu is not that high-performance.

**The question is, what is the best way to enable/disable menuItems based on a row value so that the menuItems for each row?**

### EDIT:

After adding following code:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="form:tabView:ctxJobs" />
```

the `contextMenu` does update as needed, but **only** when left clicking. When using a right-click only, the context menu doesn't update as needed. This hints that the right-click does not trigger the `rowSelect` event. There are a few questions about this topic but I would like to not use JavaScript for a solution

Comment: I think this has been asked many times before about dynamically changing the context menu on the datatable.  Search through google and stack overflow...  https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=41973

Comment: Seems wrong to require that much JavaScript to simply update the context menu before it shows. Even more when a "PrimeFaces Core Developer" says: `I don't think you require any custom script for dynamically disabled or rendered contextmenu menuitems.And you don't need to invoke the contextmenu explicitly.i.e, You can dynamically change contextmenu items based on selected row data`

Comment: I deleted my answer because the workaround to [this issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4448) works better than my attempt. I must have done something wron initally trying to test the workaround.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer PF is an open source project so you can a) provide a PR to fix it for the whole community or b) pay PrimeTek for a once time fix.  If you are not interested in either a) or b) then you are left with c) the provided workaround.